# How can we create custom slider?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I want to create a slider which contain a different slider handle and i want to paint it according to slider handle position in the slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want a slider that changes not only its position but also its appearance as you slide, right? For example, a mix of QDial and QSlider, ie. a slider with a turning knob.

If so, you will need to subclass either QSlider or QAbstractSlider (or QDial) and do the painting in your own paintEvent(). Note, however, that you will loose all style-awareness unless you care about that yourself (and that is an interesting topic in itself, see http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/style-reference.html for more info).

The Qt demos and examples, or the QSlider/QDial source code itself may serve as examples on how to overload a paintEvent().

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should look at this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qslider

Comment: Read about Style Sheets in Qt

Comment: The style-sheet approach is useful and very powerful to change the general look of a widget (or your whole application), ie. color, background-color, etc. But you can't do any manual painting with them, so I think in this case this is not what is wanted.

Comment: Additionally stylesheets automatically drop all dependence on currently used style, so widget look out-of-place.

Comment: sorry then, i missunderstood your question. However you may even with Qt CSS you may vary widget look depending on property value

Answer (score 1):

You could use QProxyStyle to ovrride drawComplexControl method - you will have to draw entire control on your own, as there is no separate flags in QStyle::ControlElement for parts of QSlider.